# Is is possible to transfer data between a windows forms application and a xamrin android application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xamarin.forms

I plan on creating a Xamarin android application. I already have a windows forms .NET application created. I was wondering if it was a way to connect the two to have a transfer of data between them. Or if it is not for a windows form application, then can i connect a .NET web application to the Xamarin app?

*addition to the question
I actually have a .net windows form app to read and generate qr codes. I plan on making an app to scan the qr codes and send information present the code to the winform application. aAll the devices would be connected over the same wifi network. so if you can point direction on what will be the best way to do it?

Comment: You can try to use REST webservice  to achieve the transfer data between applications. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest

Answer (score 0):

There are actually quite a few options to do that.

- run a web service which offers a rest interface for both your Windows application and your mobile app.
- send data via tcp or udp to your phone using wifi
- establish a bluetooth connection to send data over

However, your question is quite broad and without knowing what you want to do and why, it is hard to foresee what your requirements are and what would be the best solution for your particular scenario.

Comment: I actually have a .net windows form app to read and generate qr codes. I plan on making an app to scan the qr codes and send information present the code to the winform application. aAll the devices would be connected over the same wifi network. so if you can point direction on what will be the best way to do it?

Comment: *"There are actually quite a few options"* - how about IPC, which also includes all possible communications? *"your question is quite broad"* - that's why we have vote to close question as broad.

Comment: I have hacked a small test a while ago to send udp data over wifi from a wpf .net application to a Xamarin.Forms app, which would create a local notification. Maybe that can help you to get started. See https://github.com/mmichelbb/UdpNotificationTest

Comment: @Sinatr I added some extra information to the question